# xslt 2.0 tokenize and group

Tags: xml, xslt, text, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have an text file with following data:

```
<t>Heros
Firstname Sean
Lastname Connery
DOB 25-08-1930

Films
Dr.No 1962
Goldfinger 1964
Thunerball 1965

Award
name Academy
time 1

Award
name BAFTA
time 2

Award
name Gloden Globes
time 3</t>
```

Expected output should look like:

```
<Jamesfilms>
    <heros>
        <firstName>Sean</firstName>
        <lastName>Connery</lastName>
        <DOB>25-08-1930</DOB>
    </heros>
    <films>
        <Dr.No>1962</Dr.No>
        <Goldfinger>1964</Goldfinger>
        <Thunerball>1965</Thunerball>
    </films>
    <award>
        <name>Academy</name>
        <times>1</times>
    </award>
    <award>
        <name>BAFTA</name>
        <times>2</times>
    </award>
    <award>
        <name>Gloden Globes</name>
        <times>3</times>
    </award>
</Jamesfilms>
```

the text file content are space separator key value pairs, how to divide key values and generate XML node?

**EDIT:** I have tried [Daniel Haley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33790190/1066779) answer, and trying to resolve below exception:

```
Error at xsl:for-each on line 10 of transformer.xslt:
  XTDE1170: Invalid relative URI: Illegal character in path at index 5:
```

Java class:

```
    final String TXT_PATH = "E:/tmp/test/input.txt";
    final String XSLT_PATH = "E:/tmp/test/txtToXml.xslt";
    final String XML_PATH = "E:/tmp/test/test_xml_result.xml";

    TransformerFactory tFactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(XSLT_PATH)));
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(TXT_PATH)),new StreamResult(new File(XML_PATH)));
```

and modified xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="input-encoding" as="xs:string" select="'iso-8859-1'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="initData" as="node()">
    <Jamesfilms>
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text(., $input-encoding),'\r?\n\r?\n')">
        <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(.,'\r?\n')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$tokens[1] castable as xs:QName">
            <xsl:element name="{$tokens[1]}">
              <xsl:for-each select="$tokens[position() > 1]">
                <xsl:variable name="tokens2" select="tokenize(.,'\s')"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="$tokens2[1] castable as xs:QName">
                    <xsl:element name="{$tokens2[1]}">
                      <xsl:value-of select="$tokens2[position()>1]" separator=" "/>
                    </xsl:element>                      
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:message terminate="yes">Invalid element name: <xsl:value-of select="$tokens2[1]"/></xsl:message>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>            
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:message terminate="yes">Invalid element name: <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[1]"/></xsl:message>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Jamesfilms>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$initData"/>    
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Add additional templates to do further transforming of the initial data ($initData).-->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @voters please leave an comment, so that i can improve my SO.

Comment: It looks like the entire text file is being treated as the uri. What value are you setting your `input-uri` parameter to? Also, I see that you added a `t` element to the text file (which makes it an XML file). Is this really the case? If so my answer is not going to work as-is.

Comment: @DanielHaley from Java class `input-uri` param value is set as text file name. and `<t>` i have added to avoid exception like: `file:/E:/tmp/test/input.txt; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog`

Comment: @DanielHaley i have removed input source `input-uri` from xslt file, as am passing from java class.

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to group; you could just tokenize (and tokenize and tokenize...).

Here's an example. It doesn't do anything with the case of the element names. You can either handle those changes during the building of `$initData`, or you can add additional templates to handle any changes.

Also, the element names have to be valid QNames. Right now the stylesheet terminates processing with a message, but you can change how that's handled.

This should at least get you started...

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="input-encoding" as="xs:string" select="'iso-8859-1'"/>
  <xsl:param name="input-uri" as="xs:string" select="'so.txt'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="initData" as="node()">
    <Jamesfilms>
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text($input-uri, $input-encoding),'\r?\n\r?\n')">
        <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(.,'\r?\n')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$tokens[1] castable as xs:QName">
            <xsl:element name="{$tokens[1]}">
              <xsl:for-each select="$tokens[position() > 1]">
                <xsl:variable name="tokens2" select="tokenize(.,'\s')"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="$tokens2[1] castable as xs:QName">
                    <xsl:element name="{$tokens2[1]}">
                      <xsl:value-of select="$tokens2[position()>1]" separator=" "/>
                    </xsl:element>                      
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:message terminate="yes">Invalid element name: <xsl:value-of select="$tokens2[1]"/></xsl:message>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>            
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:message terminate="yes">Invalid element name: <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[1]"/></xsl:message>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Jamesfilms>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$initData"/>    
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Add additional templates to do further transforming of the initial data ($initData).-->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**EDIT**

You're passing the text file in as the input of the transform. That's why you had to add the `<t>` element.

Since you don't actually have an XML input, you can pass the stylesheet itself in as input. Nothing will get processed because we're only applying-templates to the variable in the template that matches root (`/`).

You also need to set the `input-uri` parameter with `transformer.setParameter("input-uri", TXT_PATH);`. If your path is absolute, be sure to add the `file:///` protocol.

Example...

**Text File**

```
Heros
Firstname Sean
Lastname Connery
DOB 25-08-1930

Films
Dr.No 1962
Goldfinger 1964
Thunerball 1965

Award
name Academy
time 1

Award
name BAFTA
time 2

Award
name Gloden Globes
time 3
```

**Java** (you'll need to change paths/filenames)

```
final String TXT_PATH = "file:///C:/tmp/input.txt";
final String XSLT_PATH = "C:/tmp/txt2xml.xsl";
final String XML_PATH = "C:/tmp/test_xml_result.xml";

TransformerFactory tFactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(XSLT_PATH)));
transformer.setParameter("input-uri", TXT_PATH);
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(XSLT_PATH)),new StreamResult(new File(XML_PATH)));
```

**XSLT 2.0**

*Same as above.*

**Output**

```
<Jamesfilms>
   <Heros>
      <Firstname>Sean</Firstname>
      <Lastname>Connery</Lastname>
      <DOB>25-08-1930</DOB>
   </Heros>
   <Films>
      <Dr.No>1962</Dr.No>
      <Goldfinger>1964</Goldfinger>
      <Thunerball>1965</Thunerball>
   </Films>
   <Award>
      <name>Academy</name>
      <time>1</time>
   </Award>
   <Award>
      <name>BAFTA</name>
      <time>2</time>
   </Award>
   <Award>
      <name>Gloden Globes</name>
      <time>3</time>
   </Award>
</Jamesfilms>
```

However, since you're using Saxon you could use the [s9api](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!javadoc/net.sf.saxon.s9api) and specify an initial template. This is the way I would do it instead of passing the stylesheet as the input to the transform.

Example...

**Java**

```
final String TXT_PATH = "file:///C:/tmp/input.txt";
final String XSLT_PATH = "C:/tmp/txt2xml.xsl";
final String XML_PATH = "C:/tmp/test_xml_result.xml";

Processor processor = new Processor(false);
Serializer serializer = processor.newSerializer();
serializer.setOutputFile(new File(XML_PATH));
XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
XsltExecutable executable = compiler.compile(new StreamSource(new File(XSLT_PATH)));
XsltTransformer transformer = executable.load();
transformer.setInitialTemplate(new QName("root"));
transformer.setParameter(new QName("input-uri"), new XdmAtomicValue(TXT_PATH));
transformer.setDestination(serializer);
transformer.transform();
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="input-encoding" as="xs:string" select="'iso-8859-1'"/>
  <xsl:param name="input-uri" as="xs:string"/>

  <xsl:variable name="initData" as="node()">
    <Jamesfilms>
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text($input-uri, $input-encoding),'\r?\n\r?\n')">
        <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(.,'\r?\n')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$tokens[1] castable as xs:QName">
            <xsl:element name="{replace($tokens[1],'\s','')}">
              <xsl:for-each select="$tokens[position() > 1]">
                <xsl:variable name="tokens2" select="tokenize(.,'\s')"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="$tokens2[1] castable as xs:QName">
                    <xsl:element name="{$tokens2[1]}">
                      <xsl:value-of select="$tokens2[position()>1]" separator=" "/>
                    </xsl:element>                      
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:message terminate="yes">Invalid element name: <xsl:value-of select="$tokens2[1]"/></xsl:message>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>            
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:message terminate="yes">Invalid element name: <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[1]"/></xsl:message>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Jamesfilms>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$initData"/>    
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Add additional templates to do further transforming of the initial data ($initData).-->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input and output would be the same. Let me know if you need me to add the java imports to the example.

Comment: I have started with your solution, am getting message as you explained, is there any way to make the element names have to be valid QNames?

Comment: @Rembo - Glad I could help 