# Transform multiple input XML documents with XSLT in a Java application using the Saxon9HE API

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

How can I transform multiple XML input document objects with a single XSL transformation script using the Saxon9HE processor in a Java application?

I found a way to transform multiple XML input files from the filesystem with an XSLT script [here](http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/79311-how-process-multiple-input-xml-files-single-xslt.html), but I can't figure out how to pass multiple loaded XML Document objects to a Java application utilizing the Saxon9HE API. For a single XML document my code looks like this and works:

```
    Processor proc = new Processor(false);

    XsltCompiler comp = proc.newXsltCompiler();

    try {
        XsltExecutable exp = comp.compile(new StreamSource(stylesheetFile));

        XdmNode source = proc.newDocumentBuilder().build(new DOMSource(inputXML));          
        Serializer out = proc.newSerializer();

        out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "xml");
        out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");
        out.setOutputFile(new File(outputFilename));

        XsltTransformer trans = exp.load();

        trans.setInitialContextNode(source);
        trans.setDestination(out);
        trans.transform();
    } catch (SaxonApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: The referenced stylesheet takes some parameters with file names or URIs you can pass in. So you can use http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltTransformer.html#setParameter(net.sf.saxon.s9api.QName,%20net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmValue) to set such parameters.

Comment: Thank you. But doesn't that mean that I can only pass files from the file system or internet via name again? Instead, I want to pass Java XML Document objects loaded and processed from another source. Do I have to save them to XML files in the file system to be able to pass them to the Saxon Transformer?

Comment: If you want to build the document in your application then you can do that as well I am sure, you might need to change `<xsl:variable name="doc2" select="document($f2)"/>` to `<xsl:param name="doc2"/>` in the referenced stylesheet and then you can set the parameter named `doc2` to an `XdmNode` you build in your application, using the `setParameter` method. As you seem to have DOM nodes, you might even be able to pass them in directly, but I am not sure which is the cleaner approach, I am sure, with the question tagged as saxon, Michael Kay will tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First point: avoid DOM if you can. When you are using Saxon, it's best to let Saxon build the document tree; this will be far more efficient. If you really need to use an external tree model, XOM and JDOM2 are much more efficient than DOM.

If you do want to provide a DOM as input, you have two choices: you can copy it to a Saxon tree, or you can wrap it as a Saxon tree. Use DocumentBuilder.build() in the first case, DocumentBuilder.wrap() in the second. Using build() gives you a higher initial cost, but the transformation itself is then faster.

If you want to pass pre-built trees into the transformation, declare the parameter using `<xsl:param name="x" as="document-node()"/>`, and then invoke the transformation using `transformer.setParameter(new QName('x'), doc)` where doc is an instance of XdmNode. You have to construct the XdmNode yourself by using a DocumentBuilder.

(Alternatively, if you want to access the documents in the stylesheet using the doc() or document() functions, you can invent a URI naming scheme and implement this in a URIResolver. When doc('my:uri') is called, your URIResolver is notified, and it should respond with a Source object. If you already have an XdmNode handy, then you can return XdmNode.asSource() to return this document tree as the result of your URIResolver.)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is indeed what I was looking for! I have to use DOM objects right now because a Java library I need returns XML data in this form. One question, though: if I specify the loaded XML trees via the "transformer.setParameter(new QName('x'), doc)" method, should I still pass one of the trees as the "initialContextNode"? I was under the impression that this would include that specific tree twice (once via setParameter and once via setInitialContextNode), but omitting it gives me a SaxonApiException (need either source doc, initial template or initial function).

Comment: @scholt, that sample stylesheet you linked to expects an initial document as the context node and then two additional documents as parameters. If you only want to work with parameters then you have to use a named template as a starting point (e.g. `<xsl:template name="main">...</xsl:template>`).

Comment: @scholt - If you need it, I have an example of using an initial named template with the s9api in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788966/xslt-2-0-tokenize-and-group

Comment: @DanielHaley  thanks for linking your answer. I am still not able to process both input XML files because the transformer seems to end in some kind of endless loop when I invoke "transform()". I guess I made some stupid XSL error. My stripped down XSLT skript looks like this (and still provokes the error): `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"><xsl:param name="qdc" as="document-node()" /><xsl:template match="@*|node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template><xsl:template match="/" name="root"><xsl:apply-templates select="$qdc" /></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks for pointing that out. I have now set a named template as the starting point and called `trans.setInitialTemplate(new QName("root"));`, after adding the XdmNodes like this `trans.setParameter(new QName("qdc", myNode);`

Comment: @scholt, consider to ask about further problems as new questions. If you use `<xsl:apply-templates select="$qdc" />` you are processing a document node and your template for that is `match="/"` which processed that same node again and again. So you would need to remove the `match="/"` from your named template or you need to use `<xsl:apply-templates select="$qdc/node()"/>` to process the child nodes or you need to introduce modes.

Comment: @MartinHonnen great, thank you, that solved this issue! And you are right, I will open new questions when I encounter additional issues. I just wasn't sure if Michaels answer already solved my problem, since I wasn't able to test it successfully (because of the stalled Java process). But now I can accept the answer!